# Strcpy Output in C

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *a = "abcde";
    char *b = "vwxyz";
    char s[10];

    strcpy(s,a+3);
    printf("%s\n",s);

    strcpy(s+2,b);
    printf("%s\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

I am having a small issue figuring out why the second strcpy(s+2,b) outputs devwxyz.

I understand the first part because it points at a[3] and counts from then to the null character which is just 'de'.

The output is:

de

devwxyz

Basically, I don't know how to find "s+2" and I'm not sure why it is 'de' in the beginning of the final output. 'devwxyz'

Hope someone can help, thanks guys.

EDIT:

I attempted to figure it out with this piece of code and it seems the indexing didn't work for me..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *a = "abcde";
    char *b = "vwxyz";
    char s[10];

    strcpy(s,a+0);
    printf("%s\n",s);

    strcpy(s+1,b);
    printf("%s\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope someone can explain, because the first strcpy results in abcde. And with s[1] that would be upto the letter 'b' so wouldn't it be abvwxyz? The correct result is avwxyz though.

Comment: Read up on pointer arithmetic. `s`, after it decays to a pointer, points to element `0` of the array. `s + 2` points to element `2` of the array.

Comment: `s+2` point at `s[2]`.

Comment: *I don't know how to find "s+2"* -- Are you saying you don't know how to count to 2? *I'm not sure why it is 'de' in the beginning of the final output.* -- Why wouldn't it be? You copied "de" into s and didn't later change it. *Hope someone can help, thanks guys.* -- It's hard to figure out which obvious thing you aren't understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two calls to `strcpy()`. The first copies "de" just as you described.

The second one copies "vwxyz" to the address of the third character in `s` (`s + 2`). Since `s` is just two characters long, it effectively appends "vwxyz" to "de".

Comment: Perfect explanation! I can see how that works now! Thanks a lot buddy!

Answer (score 0):

You find s+2 the same way you found a+3.  In this case, the third character of s is the \0 that got copied over the first time (and is replaced by this strcpy).