# Strcpy Indexing Output

Tags: c

I attempted to figure it out with this piece of code and it seems the indexing didn't work for me..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *a = "abcde";
    char *b = "vwxyz";
    char s[10];

    strcpy(s,a+0);
    printf("%s\n",s);

    strcpy(s+1,b);
    printf("%s\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope someone can explain, because the first strcpy results in abcde. And with s[1] that would be upto the letter 'b' so wouldn't it be abvwxyz? The correct result is avwxyz though.

Comment: This is very nearly a duplicate of another question you posted an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21445881/827263

Comment: Why you posted the same question again?

Comment: Sorry about that, but this question isnt the same as the first piece of code, and I was having issues getting it to work with the way you showed me, (I guess I didn't fully understand it), but going through the comments, from what I see, you have to look at the index and thencopy the vwxyz at that specified index.

Answer (score 1):

> wouldn't it be `abvwxyz`?

No. It will give `avwxyz` as output. `s+1` points to the second element of the array `s`(after decaying), i.e, `b`. Copy would started from letter `b`. `b` is overwritten by `v`.

Answer (score 0):

'avwxyz' is the correct answer. This is because strcpy replaces the character at the specified index, you probably want to do s+2 which would result in 'abwxyz'